# making JOptionPane disappear

Tags: java, swing

```
public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (frame, "Exit game?", "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            dispose ();
        }
        else
        {
            frame.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

So when the user clicks on the close button, a JOptionPane pops up. When the user clicks on "No" the JOptionpane is supposed to disappear and then return to the frame it was originally displaying, but with my code, even when I click on No, both frames, the one for the JOptionPane and the one it sits on, disappear.

One thing:

- I know I should not create a new JFrame for a JOptionPane, but I tried using `this` for the component, like: `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (this, "...",...)` when the user clicks on "No" the JOptionPane is  the only thing that's supposed to disappear (so I set it to: `this.setVisible(false);`) but when I use `this` even the main frame disappears, so I just thought to create a new frame to meet my needs. I can't set it to null either because I need it to appear at the center of the screen. If anyone could advise me on how to handle this, please do.

Comment: Why do you do frame.setVisible(false)? You don't really need that else, the JOptionPane will disappear when you click yes or no.

Comment: Why do you create new JFrame? you can just put `null` as fisrt parameter of `show confirm dialog` instead.

Comment: @peeskillet It's for a `JFrame`, but yes I'm planning to also apply it to a number of `JDialog`s because I have some of them in the `JFrame`

Comment: @kajacx yeah i know it's not necessary but i can't set it to `null` because i need it to appear at the center of the screen? Because I've tried setting a component once to null and it was a little off center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple, your frame disappear because you say that it should not be visible, just remove that else:

```
public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {         
   int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (this, "Exit game?", "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

   if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      dispose();
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also replace `setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` with `setDefaultCloseOperation (DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`, else the main frame would close regardless of what happens in the windowClosing method.

Comment: I did but both frames still disappear? =$

Comment: And what if you put that JFrame outside the method?

Comment: The code on your answer is the exact code I have now, and the `JOptionPane` and the frame still disappear even when I click on no ;/ I'm not getting any errors I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: How do you call ``windowClosing``?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question, but well I do have `addWindowListener(this)` in the constructor, then right after the closing brace of the constructor, I wrote the `windowClosing` method and the rest of the `WindowListener` which are empty because it's just the window closing event that I want to handle

Comment: Do you have ``frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`` declared somewhere? If not, then put it in where you declare your frame.

Comment: You're welcome, had a similar problem a year ago. :D

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put `else` if you don't want to hide the `frame`. The [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) will disappear by itself, whether you click yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new `JFrame` in the method. That's why you have random frame from now where.

```
public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Pass the reference of the `JFrame` in question.  If the code above is from a `JDialog` you can do something like this

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public MyDialog(final JFrame frame, boolean modal) {
        super(frame, modal);

        public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {

            int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (frame, "Exit game?", "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                dispose ();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And just instantiate the `JDialog` like this from your GUI class with the `JFrame`

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(thisFrame, true);
```

---

**Side Note**

Why Even have a `JOptionPane` *and* a `JDialog`? Ultimately, a `JDialog` is just a custom `JOptionPane`, they have the same functionality.

---

**EDIT**

If you just want to pass the `JFrame` class as reference to the `JOPtionPane` just pass

```
MyFrameClass.this
```

instead of a `new JFrame()`

---

**UDPATE**

Test out this program using a simple custom `JDialog`.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JDialogExample extends JFrame {

    public JDialogExample() {
        JButton exit = new JButton("Do you want to Exit?");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new HelloDialog(JDialogExample.this, true);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(exit);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class HelloDialog extends JDialog {

        public HelloDialog(final JFrame frame, boolean modal) {
            super(frame, modal);

            JButton exit = new JButton("EXIT");
            JButton cancel = new JButton("CANCEL");

            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(exit);
            panel.add(cancel);

            add(new JLabel("Do you want to exit?", JLabel.CENTER));
            add(panel);

            exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dispose();
                }
            });

            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JDialogExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the `JDialog`s to illustrate the plot line of the game (graphics and buttons (using .jpg files)), so instead of creating new frames, I just used `JDialog`s and for the `JOptionPane` it seemed easier to use one since I just want to show a confirming dialog for the user when he clicks on the close button.

Comment: At the moment I'm only trying the code on the `JFrame`. I haven't added the window listener yet to the `JDialog`s

Comment: Check out my **UPDATE**. It uses a simple `JDialog`. See if you can gain something from it.

Comment: My class, which is `PFrame` extends (directly) JFrame. 
Am I right in writing this? :
`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (PFrame.this, "Exit game?"....)`?

Comment: hbsrud already had the answer to my problem (it's in the comments though), but +1 for this! Thanks again!